# Display images from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a database with a lot of images. I would like to display all of the images below each other.

The structure of the database looks like this:

```
id – (int10)
name – text
likes – int(3)
url – varchar(16)
```

Below each image the number of likes should be displayed and if I click the images I go to the  url.

I would really appreciate if someone could solve this problem!

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds rather trivial if you know how to use a database (which is covered by the manual and several thousands of tutorials).

Comment: What problem? the SQL query? The PHP code? The HTML output?

Comment: This is not a problem. Please provide the problems you encountered.

Comment: There are plenty of places to hire someone to write code for you. Stack Overflow is **not** one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the below. Please note that using the mysql extension like this is strongly discouraged as it is deprecated. You should look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead, but I just used it for simplicity of the example.

```
    mysql_connect('address', 'user', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('databaseName') or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");

    if ($result) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
                <a href="http://mydomain.com/images/<?php echo htmlentities($row->url . '/' . $row->name); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo htmlentities($row->url . '/' . $row->name) ?>" />
                </a>
                <br />
                Likes: <?php echo htmlentities($row->likes); ?>
                <br />
            <?php }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = mysql_connect($IP, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error($db));
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$query="SELECT id, likes, url FROM [table name]";
$result=mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
echo '<a href="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "url") . '">';
echo '<img src="' . mysql_result($result, $i, "url") . '"></a>';
echo '<br>' . mysql_result($result, $i, "likes") . ' likes';
}
```

I strongly suggest you to review your PHP manual. This is quite basic coding. Also notice that the above code won't work in an empty database. `$IP` is the database IP, `$username` is the database username, `$password` is the database password. Also, I suggest you to use the MySQLi extension, as the one I use is deprecated.